# How does the function work?

Tags: f#

I faced with this code

```
let quadruple x =    
    let double x =
        x * 2
```

and it is mentioned that,
*quadruple calls the double function twice to perform an (inefficient) quadrupling.*

How does it happen?
I think quadruple gets x then x will be passed to the double which is defined in the quadrupal. As a result, it must works as a stack.

it first compute `x*2` and then return the result to quadrupal and it's over.

**So why quadruple calls the double function twice**

Comment: as-is your code is invalid raising a : Block following this 'let' [the let double one] is unfinished. Expect an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original code snippet is missing one more line. It must look like this:

```
let quadruple x =    
    let double x =
        x * 2
    double(double x)
```

Written this way, `double` is just an inner sub-function defined within `quadruple`. It is only a definition. Unless being called, it doesn't do anything.

The last line belongs to the body of `quadruple`. It indeed, first calls `double` with `x` argument and then calls it again with the received result, effectively quadrupling the original value.